# Dynamically updating page if user connects/disconnects from Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Is there a way to dynamically update a page when the user connects/disconnects the app from his facebook?

I.e using one of the event subscriber methods that come with the javascript SDK?

I'm trying `authResponseChange` however my callback function doesn't seem to get called if I delete the app from my facebook account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to also register to the *auth.statusChange* event, though from my experience neither are really reliable.

You can know on the server side when a user deauthorizes your app, in the app settings > Advanced tab there's the field *Deauthorize Callback* where you can put a url in your server which will be pinged when a user removes the app.

With that you can then synchronize your client somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually check if a user is logged in, but hasn't authorized your app, using `FB.getLoginStatus`, passing a callback function in ([see here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) in the Facebook JS SDK docs). Could you use the already existing events, and then perform checks of this kind each time? Maybe subscribe to the `auth.authResponseChange` and `auth.statusChange` events, and then call `FB.getLoginStatus` to see if it's changed.